# Firebird UDF in Linux crashes server when set to return by reference

Tags: linux, gcc, reference, firebird

I'm trying to create some simple UDF for firebird in Linux (in C compiled with GCC).
The problem is, that when I set "Return mechanism" to be "by reference", when I call the function, the server crashes.
When it's "by value", there's no problem.

Here are the functions I try to write in C:

This one works:

```
double round(double *); 
double round(val)
double *val;
{
    *val = *val * 100;
    *val = (*val>= 0) ? (long)(*val + 0.5) : (long)(*val - 0.5);
    *val = *val / 100;
    return *val;
}
```

But this one crashes the server when called:

```
char * proper_case(str)
char * str;
{
    return str;
}
```

Here are the DDLs:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION "ROUND"
    DOUBLE PRECISION
RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION BY VALUE
ENTRY_POINT 'round' MODULE_NAME 'my_udfs.so';

DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION PROPCASE
    CSTRING(10000)
RETURNS CSTRING(10000) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'proper_case' MODULE_NAME 'my_udfs.so';
```

I call second function with:

```
select propcase('abrakadabra') from rdb$database;
```

The firebird server crashes and the only error message i've got is:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = -902
Error reading data from the connection.
```

Could somebody advise? Any help will be appreciated!

The only info I forgot to provide is the way I'm compiling .so file (may be the key is here):

```
gcc -c -O -fpic my_udf.c
ld -G my_udf.o -lm -lc -o my_udf.so
cp my_udf.so /usr/lib/firebird/2.1/UDF/my_udfs.so
```

Comment: I'd suggest to check Chapter 6 of the Interbase 6.0 Developers Guide (available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ ), I haven't written a UDF yet, but I think you are allocating memory in the wrong way.

Comment: Taking a look at the code of some of the UDFs shipped with Firebird might be helpful as well: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/firebird/code/firebird/trunk/src/extlib/ib_udf.cpp

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I've copied following function from firebird SVN: pChar EXPORT IB_UDF_lower(const char *s) - and result is the same. The only change I've maid is that I've removed word EXPORT because GCC don't recognize it.

Comment: I believe `EXPORT` on most platforms is defined to do nothing anyway. I'd suggest you also contact the Firebird-core developers on the Firebird-devel mailinglist https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/firebird-devel

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Firebird will try to free both the argument and return value after the call (as it doesn't know what you do inside the function and you have declared your return value as `FREE_IT`), so you need to allocate the space for return value before returning it. You must allocate the memory with `ib_util_malloc()` call, so it would look something like (haven't even tried to compile it but it should give you the general idea):

```
char * proper_case(str)
char * str;
{
    char* ret = (char*)ib_util_malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(ret, str); // or run the actual logic here
    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: I found an example from the Firebird built in UDF lib:

```
pChar EXPORT IB_UDF_lower(const char *s)
{
if (!s) return 0;

char* buf = (char *) ib_util_malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
char* p = buf;
while (*s) {
    if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z') {
        *p++ = *s++ - 'A' + 'a';
    }
    else
        *p++ = *s++;
}
*p = '\0';

return buf;
}
```

Comment: Removing the FREE_IT from the function declaration might fix it as well (in this specific case where the returned value is identical to one of the parameters).

Comment: that's my feeling too, but I can't find the part in the docs which states that explicitly so I skipped it. Besides, as the function name implies that that the return value differs from the input, it wouldn't work in general.

Comment: May be I've missed something cardinal, but the only significant difference between working and crashing function is that first must return "by value" and second - "by reference".

Comment: @Mark - without "FREE_IT" result is the same

Comment: @DustyRaven - hmm, are you sure that the .so was updated properly (sorry for asking the obvious)? I have added an "official" UDF to my answer and it does more or less the same. Is your function properly exported?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic - sadly but yes. I've also edited some other functions (returning by value) and seen the results.

Comment: are you sure that the versions of headers/libs you are building against match the version of FB server? It shouldn't really matter unless you are linking against static libs (which I think you don't), but I can't think of another reason

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic - I've just tried to create new .so with only one function, copied from UDF lib - pChar EXPORT IB_UDF_lower(const char *s)... still result is the same - server crashes.

Comment: @DustyRaven I'd say that is an indication that there is something in your setup (compiler options, etc) that isn't set correctly, as that UDF does work in Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark, you were right. Something is wrong with compiling / linking.

This is not exactly an answer, but how I managed to fix the problem.

I am compiling UDF with these commands:

```
gcc -c -O -fpic my_udf.c
ld -G my_udf.o -lm -lc -o my_udf.so
cp my_udf.so /usr/lib/firebird/2.1/UDF/my_udfs.so
```

There was no errors, firebird server crashes also without error state.
So I've opened Python and tried following:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL("path/to/my_udf.so")
libc.IB_UDF_lower("abrakadabra")
```

Python throw error about non existing function "ib_util_malloc".
So I replace it with "malloc" and everything worked fine.

I still don't know what I'm doing wrong, but since GCC don't give me any errors, I suppose it's a linking issue.